# C Xcode question

Tags: c, xcode

I am trying to pass arguments to the command line in xCode. I have looked up this issue and have found that I need to set the working directory to the path that the file is in. Also I have to add the arguments to the arguments tab under project- edit activeexecutable. I have also done this.

I added michael.txt twice.

```
/* This file is saved as readtext.c, compiled as readtext */ 
#include <stdio.h> 
void main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{ 
    FILE *fin; 
    char buffer[100]; 
    printf("Michael Mazur\n"); 
    if (argc != 2) {printf("Usage: %s filename\n", argv[0]); exit(1);} 
    fin = fopen(argv[1], "r"); 
    if (!fin) {printf("Unable to open %s\n", argv[1]); exit(1);} 
    while (fgets(buffer, 99, fin)) fputs(buffer, stdout); 
    fclose (fin); 
}
```

I keep reaching the case that there are not 2 arguments being passed. I also ran a little test program and it keeps returning that I only have 1 argument being passed no matter how many I add. Any help?

Comment: If you run the program manually outside of xcode and supply arguments, does it work as expected?

Comment: Yes. If i run it outside of xcode it runs as expected.

Answer (score 4):

`argv[0]` (path to the executable) counts in `argc`, so if you add `michael.txt` twice, `argc` will be 3.  A slightly longer description is [here](http://notabug.com/2002/coherent/man/argc.html).  (In general, when something is misbehaving like this, either use a debugger to check the values of *all* the variables or print them out.)

Make sure both arguments are checked and on separate lines, like this:

[image: picture of xcode]

Also, in future please mention what version of Xcode you're using; I think from your description it's 3.x, so that's how I answered the question.  The user interface varies pretty substantially between versions.

Comment: Sorry about that I am using Xcode 3.2. I have the the arguments checked on seperate lines as illustrated. I still am getting the answer that 1 argument is being passed no matter how many I am passing using this little snippet of code to test:

Comment: #include <stdio.h>

void showargs(int, char **);

#define STAND_ALONE 1

#ifdef STAND_ALONE
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
 printf("Michael Mazur tessst\n");
 showargs(argc, argv);
 return (0);
}
#endif

void showargs(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
 int i;
 printf("Program name: %s\n", argv[0]);
 printf("There are %d arguments\n",argc);
 for (i=1; i<argc; i++)
  printf("%2d. %s\n",i, argv[i]);
}

Comment: Could you post your project somewhere (just zip up the directory and post it)? You might be running into an obscure Xcode bug...